can't get accessToken with client-credentials grant_type with spring-authorization-server
env:
java: 17
spring boot: 3.3.4
spring security: 6.3.3
spring authorization server: 1.3.2
i configured the authorization server like below with new version of spring-authorization-server library. i sent the request with postman which has correct client id and client secret parameter with the server. but can't get the access Token. reference is few. and can't find out the reason due to abstract.
below is my code
package authorization.demo.config;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.OidcScopes;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizationService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.AuthorizationServerSettings;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.ClientSettings;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.TokenSettings;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.UUID;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    /**
     * Protocol endpoints 를 위한 설정
     * Authorization Endpoint   /oauth2/authorize
     * Token Endpoint           /oauth2/token
     * Token Revocation         /oauth2/revoke
     * Token Introspection      /oauth2/introspect
     * JWK Set Endpoint         /oauth2/jwks
     * Authorization Server Metadata     /.well-known/oauth-authorization-server
     * OIDC Provider Configuration      /.well-known/openid-configuration
     */
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http); //OAuth2AuthorizationServer를 구동한다.
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class);
        http.exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor( // 인가 실패에 대한 처리를 정의
                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        ));

        http.oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer.jwt(withDefaults())); // '토큰 검증'에 대한 설정
        http.formLogin().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

    /**
     * 인증(Authentication)을 위한 설정
     */
    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Optional: Add specific matcher for the token endpoint to ensure no redirects
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
        http.formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withUsername("user")
                .username("user")
                .password("{noop}1234")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    /**
     * 클라이언트의 정보를 등록하고 관리하는 역할을 한다.
     */
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient client = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientName("Your client name")
                .clientId("client-id")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret") // 실제 운영환경에서는 임의의 문자열을 사용하고, 코드에 올리면 안됨
                .clientAuthenticationMethods(methods -> {
                    methods.add(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC);
                })
                .authorizationGrantTypes(types -> {
                    types.add(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS); // Client Credentials 방식 사용
                    types.add(AuthorizationGrantType.JWT_BEARER); // JWT token 사용
                    types.add(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN); // refresh Token 사용
                }) //
                .scopes(scope -> {
                    scope.add("message.read");
                })
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder().build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(client);
    }

    /**
     * jwt 생성에 필요한 RSA키 generate, 실제 운영에 사용하려면 KeyStore에 저장해야한다.
     */
    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey).privateKey(privateKey).keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    /**
     * 토큰 검증을 위한 디코더
     */
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    /**
     * Authorization server를 구성하기 위한 여러 EndPoint를 설정하는 객체
     */
    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .tokenEndpoint("oauth2/token")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizationService oAuth2AuthorizationService() {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizationService();
    }

}

and i request with post man like this.
https://i.sstatic.net/mdLCyxrD.png
https://i.sstatic.net/Qsj8UBPn.png
the spring security redirects with 302 response and getting 200 with default security login page..without acessToken... help me please. thank you for reading.

Can you place debug in converter, seem like it go into the wrong filter. And also, this flow dont require username, password, only client_id:clietn_secret with base 64

i figured by replacing the code
@Bean
public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
    return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
            .tokenEndpoint("oauth2/token")
            .build();
} 

to
@Bean
public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
    return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
            .build();
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
